# How can i call Event from controller? namespaces

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces, laravel-5.8

im trying to make notification system.
I created Event:

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class DealApproved implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $username;

    public $message;

     public function __construct($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->message  = "{$username} approved your deal#50. Please take an action!";
    }


    public function broadcastOn()
    {
         return ['notification-channel-4'];

    }



}
```

my route:

```
Route::get('/notify', 'NotificationController@approve_deal');
```

My controller:

```
<?php



namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Pusher\Pusher;
use Events\DealApproved;

class NotificationController extends Controller
{
    public function approve_deal()
    {


            event(new App\Events\DealApproved('Someone'));


    return "Event has been sent!";



    }
}
```

when i use this route:

```
Route::get('notify', function () {
    event(new App\Events\DealApproved('Someone'));
    return "Event has been sent!";
});
```

everything works fine, but when i change route to controller  i got error:

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Events\DealApproved' not found

use Events\DealApproved; didnt work, please help

Comment: you need to take a few minutes to look into how namespacing works in PHP ... this might help https://mattstauffer.co/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-php-namespacing

Answer (score 1):

Just put this line in controller `use App\Events\DealApproved;`

and change this

```
   event(new DealApproved('Someone'));
```

It should  work.